# Entity Framework with LINQ query repeats records

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Using Entity Framework 6.0 and .Net 4.5. Mapped the table `[Log]` to set the data connection using Entity Data Model Wizard and table data as below:

| timestamp | owner | message | docid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06-11-2020 10:32:49 | User1 | message-1 | 100 |
| 06-11-2020 10:32:49 | User1 | message-2 | 100 |
| 06-11-2020 10:32:50 | administrator |  | 100 |
| 06-11-2020 10:32:50 | administrator |  | 100 |
| 06-11-2020 10:32:49 | User1 | message-3 | 100 |

When I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio, it returns the proper result:

```
SELECT *  
FROM [dbo].[Log]  
WHERE docid = 100
```

But when I query using Entity Framework in my source code using below query, then it repeats the rows which is having the same timestamp:

```
var logEntries = (
        from logEty in context.Log
        where logEty.docid == 100
        orderby logEty.timestamp
        select logEty
    )
    .ToList();
    
foreach (var entry in logEntries)
{
    message = entry.message;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    message = string.Empty;
}
```

Output:

```
message-1
message-1
message-1
```

My question is why I get the records duplicated in the result. Even I removed the sort by statement. Can anyone suggest the solution and what is root cause of this problem?

Note: I don't have any primary key or any kind of constraints in the table structure.

Regards,
Suresh Kaushik

Comment: Are the rows of the table you provided full data set or just a sample? Are you sure you don't have entries with duplicated `message` column?

Comment: EF and good common sense **requires** a primary key on *any* serious table ...... if you don't have an explicit primary key on the table, then EF will use all non-nullable columns as its "substitute primary key" - and that might lead to unexpected results - like here for example .....

Comment: Rows of the table is the full data set for docid-100 and also don't have duplicate entry in message column.